# Me da error al logearme

Tags: php, html, sql

El error que me da es al intentar acceder a `apanel.php` a veces accede y a veces no, creo que es cosa de las sesiones pero no estoy seguro.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
session_start();
        include("cabecera.php");
        include("conexion.php");

    if (isset($_REQUEST['Enviar'])) {
    $usuario = $_REQUEST['ausuario'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['apass'];

    $sql = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios,apass WHERE ausuario='".$usuario."' and apass='".$password."'");
    while ($login = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $usuarioDB = $login['ausuario'];
        $passwordDB = $login['apass'];
    }
    if ($usuario == isset($usuarioDB) && password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "loggedin";
        $_SESSION['ausuario'] = $usuarioDB;
        $_SESSION['apass'] = $passwordDB;
        header("Location: apanel.php");
    } elseif ($usuario !== isset($usuarioDB)) {
        echo "<div class='error'><span>El Nombre de Usuario que has Introducido es Incorrecto</span></div>";
    } elseif (password_verify($password, $passwordDB) === FALSE) {
        echo "<div class='error'><span>La Contraseña que has Introducido es Incorrecta</span></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="login-form" class="text-left" method="post">

<br/>

<tr>
                <td><span class="fa-user"></span><input name="ausuario" placeholder="usuario" type="text" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="learText(this)" class="textfield"/><br/><br/></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="fa-lock"></span><input name="apass" placeholder="contraseña" type="password" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)" class="textfield"/><br/><br/></td></tr>

        <input type="checkbox" id="lg_remember" name="lg_remember"><label for="lg_remember">recordar</label><br/>
                                        <tr><td><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Comment: Estimado, necesita mostrar el error para tener una idea de como pueden ayudarle.

Comment: Es posible que NO quisieras seleccionar desde(FROM) la tabla **apass** en el query? Si tanto el nombre de usuarios como la contraseña(apass) están en la tabla usuarios, deja solo **usuarios** y no incluyas **apass** en el FROM.

Comment: creo que tienes razón, fue un fallo porque ahi llamas a la tabla no al campo jeje muchas gracias lo probare.

Comment: Sigue igual, no redirige a apanel.php

Answer (score 0):

en `<form id="login-form" class="text-left" method="post">` prueba con sustituir

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" class="text-left" method="post" href="#" >
```

> PHP_SELF es una variable que devuelve el script actual que se está
>   ejecutando. Esta variable devuelve el nombre y la ruta del archivo
>   actual (desde la carpeta raíz). Puede usar esta variable en el campo
>   de acción del FORMULARIO.

Usando la variable PHP_SELF puedes escribir un código más genérico que se puede usar en cualquier página y no necesitas editar el campo de acción